# Excel formula question - Working hours with business times including Saturday

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need help with formula what calculates hours between two dates and must consider business hours etc, i checked other threads and non of them covered my specific needs :/

So here is the issue:

I have already formula for standard Monday to Friday set up with starting time 9:00am and end time 17:00pm. However i also need formula what would include Saturday with different working time 9:00am and 15:00pm.

This is my current formula but i cannot seem to figure out how to add Saturday and wit different working times.

```
=(NETWORKDAYS(OpenDate_time,ClosedDate_time,Holidays)-1)*(END_TIME-START_TIME)+IF(NETWORKDAYS(ClosedDate_time, ClosedDate_time),MEDIAN(MOD(ClosedDate_time,1),END_TIME,START_TIME),END_TIME)-MEDIAN(NETWORKDAYS(OpenDate_time, OpenDate_time)*MOD(OpenDate_time,1),END_TIME,START_TIME)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I would replace all the "`NETWORKDAYS`" with `NETWORKDAYS.INTL`

The function: NETWORKDAYS.INTL(start_date, end_date, [weekend], [holidays]) has the ability to choose what you are considered as holidays. If your write 11 for weekend, you are only considered Sunday as holiday, all other days of the week is business days. 

Source: [NETWORKDAYS.INTL function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/networkdays-intl-function-a9b26239-4f20-46a1-9ab8-4e925bfd5e28?NS=EXCEL&Version=16&SysLcid=1033&UiLcid=1033&AppVer=ZXL160&HelpId=xlmain11.chm60568&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

Comment: Hey Thanks for the suggestion, i did the update and yes now i have also Saturday however only issue it is counted as regular working day and not shorter day.

Comment: Since I have no idea how your dataset is setup my logical approach would be something like: 1. - Calculate the whole time for regular 5 workdays (monday to friday) - [9-17].
2. - Calculate the whole time for 5 workdays (monday to friday) - [9-15].
3. - Calculate the whole time for 6 workdays (monday to saturday) - [9-15].
There are for sure much better ways to do it given more information :)

Subtract the difference between 2. and 3. then you should get the difference which is saturdays hours.
If you want you could add those to 1. (regular working hours).

Comment: Hey, thank you for your time to look into this, the data set is very basic – Column A Received date with date and time stamp, Column B is Closed date with the date and time stamp. 
So what I need to measure is how many business hours it takes to close the request. 
Open_Date Close_Date Hours
01-10-18 0:05 02-10-18 11:32     ?
In the example I’m showing the closing hours should be 10:32:48 considering the business hours are from 09:00 am to 17:00 pm. So 8 hours in 01/10/2018 and 2:32:48 from 02/10/2018. I hope this clarifies more my intentions. Thank you